# the program using socket to communicat has stuck

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I used socket in my program to let the client communicate with the prover namely the server. Firstly, the client send local file to the prover, and it succeed. Then, the client send signatures of that file to the prover, but the program has stuck. I think the `recv` function of the prover cannot receiver any data so it failed, but I don't know why it happend. Can anyone explain it?

```
/* send file */
if (on_cmd_send_file_client(sockProver, username, party, filename, blocksize, blocknum)) {
    printf("%s(%d)-%s:%d-%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, errno, strerror(errno));
    return (errno ? errno : -1);
}

/* send signature */
length = pairing_length_in_bytes_G1(pairing);
if (on_cmd_send_sig_client(sockProver, username, party, filename, length, blocknum)) {
    printf("%s(%d)-%s:%d-%s\n", __FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, errno, strerror(errno));
    return (errno ? errno : -1);
}
```

Comment: Where is the `recv` function of prover?

Comment: the recv function of prover is too long.

Comment: How does the prover know when the file ends and the signatures begin? In other words: What does your message protocol look like?

Comment: The client send command to the prover, if the prover receives successfully, then the client begin to send data.The prover uses a while circulation to receive comand and execute corresponding operations to receive data. The send function of the client corresponds to the recv functin of the prover. Namely, when the client send all of the file, the prover stopped receiving data, and begin to receive command. But the question is, the client send the command of send signature successfully, but the prover failed to receive the command.So the program got stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start both the client and a server in debugging mode to understand what exactly is happening. As it stands now, it is difficult to say what exactly is the cause of the communication stall. There might be a framing problem, i.e., the server waits for more data, while the client thinks it already sent everything. I saw quite many cases in which `recv` was assumed to do framing, which it does not for TCP.

Comment: yeah, I think u got the point. The prover uses a while circulation to receive command and then execute corresponding operations to receive data. I think the recv function in the circulation didn't receive command so it stuck , but don't know why.

Comment: If you posted the source code of the prover and client, I might be able to help, but right now it feels like guessing.

Comment: The source code is just too long, and it's a little project in fact. If u don't mind, can I e-mail it to u?